# Order of execution of code

Tags: android, handler

I'm using a handler at two places in my code. My code is the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        vibrator.vibrate(Constants.DEFAULT_VIBRATE_TIME);

        checkPassword();

        List<NameValuePair> userDetails = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        Utils.addCustomerLoginDetail(userDetails);
        final ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(
                ChangePasswordActivity.this, "", "Saving Please wait..");
        Ola.asyncHttpClient.get(HttpCommunicator.getFilledUrl(
                UrlConstants.AUTH_SEND_LOGIN_INFO_URL, userDetails),
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    public void onSuccess(String arg0) {
                        serverResponse = arg0;
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                verifyLoginDetails();
                            }
                        });
                    };

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        if(isRunning())
                            progress.dismiss();
                    };
                });

        if (!doValidations()
                || !isConnectedToInternet()) {
            return;
        }
        updateCustomerDetails();
        List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        Utils.addUserId(list);
        Utils.addCustomerPassword(list);
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                ChangePasswordActivity.this, "", "Saving Please wait..");

        Ola.asyncHttpClient.get(HttpCommunicator.getFilledUrl(
                UrlConstants.AUTH_UPDATE_PROFILE_URL, list),
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    public void onSuccess(String arg0) {
                        serverResponse = arg0;
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                sendCustomerDetailsToServer();
                            }
                        });
                    };

                    public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
                        showOlaDialog(Ola.NO_CONNECTIVITY);
                    };

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        if(isRunning())
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                    };
                });
    }
};
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the second part of the code (the part after the if statement) gets executed and is finished before the first part.

What do I need to do to make sure that the first part gets finished before the second part starts.

Comment: What is a "part" here? If you do things asynchronously, you by definition don't care which order they finish in.

Comment: I spotted three `if`s in your code. Which one of them where you referring to ?

Comment: I'm referring to the `if (!doValidations()|| ` `!isConnectedToInternet()) {`
            `return;`
        `}`

Answer (score 3):

Runnable is used for code that is executed on separate thread. To force a specific order use any synchronization method you like. One thread could wait an event from the first thread and after that to execute its code.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is asynchronous code above, namely `AsyncHttpResponseHandler`, you could use an [asynchronous semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_semaphore).

Semaphores enable locking a mechanism or piece of code from execution, until a certain asynchronous event occurs.